# How to Transparent in Custom Alert Dialog in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I created the custom alert dialog for my project.  When I click the button, the custom alert dialog is opened but a white background appears on my custom alert dialog.  How can I make it transparent?

**.java:**

```
 package com.example.bskes.customalertdialog;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button adbtn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            adbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCustomAD);
            adbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.rtr_mem_profile_layout, null);

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Thank You", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It's My Pleasure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setView(view);
                    builder.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this ,this will help to show transparent background of dilog

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

First line show the transparent layer on background and second line provide the actual size of the your window view.
 it help me, use it

Answer (score 0):

define what follows in the `styles.xml` file

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and pass it as argument to the AlertDialog constructor

```
AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubProducts.this, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Or programmatically, through the Dialog instance you can call

```
myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Comment: doesn't work for me sir app crash when i use this method thx for suggest sir

Comment: when i open custom alertdialog the main activity body color is change to black color and after close it the black color randomly generate

Answer (score 0):

> Add this to your styles.xml file

```
  <style name="MyDialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

> Add this to your java file :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.MyDialog);
```

Comment: sir i'm using custom layout so it's doesn't work for me thx for ur suggest sir